# WPF Button in ContextMenu needs StaysOpenOnClick

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, contextmenu

I use a ContextMenu with Buttons in it. 
Whenever the special Button is pressed I want the ContextMenu to be closed. 
I saw a possibility for a MenuItem which is called "StaysOpenOnClick".. this works perfectly fine.

This is what I need for the Button.. Especially a XAML only solution would be nice to have if anyone can help out!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your XAML look like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could close the ContextMenu by animating its IsOpen property using a BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames. This is a XAML only solution:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Width="50" Height="50">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sb">
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu">
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Button Content="TheButton" Click="OnButtonClick" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
            <ContextMenu.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sb}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </ContextMenu.Triggers>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

> This solution works, but the ContextMenu now gets closed for all buttons in my ContextMenu. I just wanted it to be closed with only one button called "Settings".

In this case you could set the SourceName property of the EventTrigger to the x:Name of the "Settings" Button:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="sb">
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu">
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <Button Content="Settings" x:Name="settingsButton" />
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <Button Content="About" />
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <ContextMenu.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="settingsButton">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sb}" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ContextMenu.Triggers>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: I guess you don't need the Click Event for the button. Anyway this solution works, but the ContextMenu now gets closed for all buttons in my ContextMenu. I just wanted it to be closed with only one button called "Settings".

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Please also remember to accept and vote it up if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're after, but here is a context menu with a button:

```
<TextBlock
    Text="Hello, world!">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu">
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Button Content="MyButton" Click="OnMenuButtonClick" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

If you handle the button click as follow, it will close the context menu:

```
private void OnMenuButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    contextMenu.IsOpen = false;
}
```

(Not a XAML-only solution, though.)

Comment: if you change button to toggle button you should be able to bind to the IsOpen property removing the code behind